# How do I modify this .htaccess rule so it can accommodate two scenarios?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The following .htaccess rule replaces "OLDNAME" with "NEWNAME" in a URL and it removes the string "-2" from the end of the URL if it exists. I need to update the rule to accommodate two scenarios: "OLDNAME1" and "OLDNAME2". Both redirect to a single "NEWNAME".

```
RewriteRule ^(index\.php/)?OLDNAME/(.+?)(?:-2)?/?$ /NEWNAME/$2 [L,NC,R=302,NE]
```

I've tried several variations of the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(index\.php/)?(OLDNAME1|OLDNAME2)/(.+?)(?:-2)?/?$ /NEWNAME/$2 [L,NC,R=302,NE]
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close, you can do like this:

```bash
# /nwblog => /blog
RewriteRule ^(?:index\.php/)?nwblog/(.+?)(?:-2)?/?$ /blog/$1 [L,NC,R=302,NE]

# remove /index.php/
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.+)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=302,NE]

# remove /-2
RewriteRule ^(.+)-2/?$ /$1 [L,NC,R=302,NE]
```

Comment: I've cleared my browser cache and the dynamic caching on the server, but I get an error that reads "This page is not working." Could it have anything to do with the actual names of OLDNAME and NEWNAME? The actual names are as follows: OLDNAME1=nwblog. OLDNAME2 = blog, NEWNAME=blog.

Comment: If both `OLDNAME2` and `NEWNAME` are `blog` then it would cause looping. Let me suggest you another approach.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples please try following .htaccess rules file. We need to use `THE_REQUEST` variable here and also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/?index\.php/?\?(?:OLDNAME[12])(.+?)(?:-2)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /NEWNAME/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: `(?:1|2)` can be simplified to `[12]`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to get this to work.